# Is there an analytical way to solve this system of equations?

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

I have to solve this system of equations for one class and I have to iterate, which I hate (the class is applied hydraulics). The system is the following:

$$h_1-H=a \cdot Q_1^2 $$
$$h_2-H=b \cdot Q_2^2 $$
$$H-h_3=c \cdot Q_3^2 $$

Where $h_1$, $h_2$, $h_3$, $a$, $b$ and $c$ are known.

I think I can dispose of the second equation, because depending of the case it can be written as: $H-h_2=b \cdot Q_2^2 $ depending on the case.

Comment: You have 3 equations with 4 unknowns: $H, Q_1, Q_2, Q_3$.  Do you know anything else?

Comment: That I can use $h_2-H$ and $H-h_2$ interchangably. No more from that.

Comment: That does not make too much sense. If $h_2-H=H-h_2$ it means $H=h_2$, and if $b\ne 0$ then $Q_2=0$. I assume you mean something else. Since you are talking about an applied class, I think these quantities have meaning. That might imply some extra relationship. For example, what are the $Q$ quantities?